# What .NET type marshalls to COM UINT?

Tags: com, com-interop, idl

In C# I am declaring an interface, which will be exposed to COM for use by C++. Our spec says one integer parameter should be `[in]UINT uiVal`. I'm using `int` in C# and it is being exposed as `long`.

It's not a big deal, but how can I force it to marshall to `UINT` rather than `long`? Some specific .Net type, or do I need to add attributes to the C# parameter somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UINT is a type alias from the Windows SDK, you will never get it out of a type library.  Tooling that translates type libraries, like the #import directive you are using, pick native C types.  History plays a role, COM was originally designed for the 16-bit version of Windows.  When *long* was important to declare a 32-bit integer.

Closest you can get is `uint` in the C# declaration, it will be translated to `unsigned long` in your C++ code.  Which is fine, it is still a 32-bit type, Microsoft chose the [LLP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) for 64-bit code.  They did not have much of a choice.  Unlike the LP64 model chosen in *nix.  They did not have much of a choice either, the Y2K38 disaster is approaching fast :)